# SMTP load issues?

Tags: asp.net, smtp

I'm in the process of making a new ASP.NET MVC and I'm just curious if I need to choose a SMTP provider carefully. I'm thinking of launching on Azure or Amazon and possibly using one of their SMTP solutions. But if I don't go cloud, I'm wondering how much of an issue SMTP load is?

Is it not an issue at all? I.E if I have say 10 emails going out every minute, do I need a SMTP server with a certain capacity, queuing e.t.c?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 emails per min (or even 100 per min) is likely a non-issue for a run of the mill SMTP server to handle.

However, there are good reasons for going with a SMTP forwarding solution. (I've used the dyndns SMTP relay solution to great effect).

Essentially, your concern will be deliverability. Its quite easy to slap together an email server that can reach 80% of your targets....it gets a bit more complicated to get a 99.9999% solution for deliveries.

There are lots of little things: Has the originating IP been blacklisted on any of the RBL sites, do you have proper reverse DNS setup on that IP, are you virus / phish scanning all your outgoing emails (failure to do so may land your IP on a blacklist, which is then tedious to clear).

In short, the $10 a month (or whatever) is a bargain when facing the nitty gritty hassles of managing your own server.

Comment: Thanks a lot , great response, I need very good delivery rates, for activation emails e.t.c, so will look into these solutions

Answer (score 1):

If you have on the order of 10 emails per minute, load will be a non-issue.

Deliverability may be a larger concern.  If you run your own SMTP server from the Amazon cloud, you may find that the AWS IP ranges are used by some recipient servers as a negative factor when calculating the spam probability.

Whatever solution you select should provide a stable IP address ideally just for your traffic.  If others send spammy emails from the same IP address, it will affect your sender reputation as well.

I have not used services such as [Amazon's Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or [SendGrid](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sendgrid-email-service/) (we manage SMTP servers and our sender reputation directly, with the help of Return Path), but would expect that they likely do a good job of maintaining the sender reputation of their clients.

Comment: Great answer thankyou! didn't realise deliverability would be such an issue. I need to send things like Activation emails e.t.c so clearly they MUST arrive. Will look into Amazon, SendGrid and freetx's dynds